# How to troubleshoot a GPF?

Tags: windows-xp, freeze, svchost

I get a GPF dialog box out of the blue fairly often (like about 2 hours after I turn on the computer).  It basically says that svchost.exe had a failure... (see the corresponding Event Log entry below).

```
Event Type:   Error Event
Source:       Application Error Event
Category:     (100) 
Event ID:     1000
Date:         5/18/2010 
Time:         7:41:16 PM
User:       
N/A Computer: DKHA-IPSA
Description:  Faulting application svchost.exe, version 5.1.2600.5512, 
  faulting module ole32.dll, version 5.1.2600.5512, fault address 0x0004eaa9.
```

Shortly after this error pops up, the computer pretty much grinds to a halt (e.g. some UI elements on the desktop simply do not respond).  And I have to do a hard reboot.

How do I troubleshoot this type of thing?

P.S.  The PC has all the latest patches and nothing is missing in the Device Manager.

Comment: Does it say which PID the faulting `svchost.exe` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

procmon from microsoft.com will help greatly in this case, best guess is a virus!
tr